# Unexpectedly jquery validation shows only first required message

Tags: jquery, validation

I do not do sth like $(sth)validate{} in a project and it is working like i expected but in another project i can see only one validation error message, first one, then i fill it, and click submit button, it does not check other inputs:

my own function is below, i can see "here" after i enter a value for "First Name", but i need error messages if i do not enter for middle name and surname too.

```
function assembleAndSaveContact(){

if($("form#form_validation_reg_generate_contact").valid()){
console.log('here');
}
}
```

xhtml code:

```
<!-- validation -->
<script src='#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/validation/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
<!-- sticky messages -->
<script src='#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/sticky/sticky.min.js'></script>
<script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li><a onclick="assembleAndSaveContact();" class="btn-mini" href="#" style="float: left;"><i class="splashy-mail_light_new_2"></i>Save and Close </a></li>
<fieldset>
    <form id="form_validation_reg_generate_contact">
         Profile
        <div style="clear: both; height: 1px; background: #CCCCCC;margin-bottom: 6px; margin-top: 6px">
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 6px">
            <div class="span4" style="margin: 0px">
                <label class="control_label_compose"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#adrBook">First Name</a></label>
            </div>
            <div class="span8" style="margin: 0px">
                <input class="span12 required" type="text" id="firstName"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 6px">
            <div class="span4" style="margin: 0px">
                <label class="control_label_compose"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#adrBook">Middle Name</a></label>
            </div>
            <div class="span8" style="margin: 0px">
                <input class="required span12" type="text" id="middleName"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group" style="margin-bottom: 6px">
            <div class="span4" style="margin: 0px">
                <label class="control_label_compose"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#adrBook">Last Name</a></label>
            </div>
            <div class="span8" style="margin: 0px">
                <input class="span12 required" type="text" id="lastName"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Unless you've missed out some stuff when copying/pasting, your HTML is invalid: an `li` element is an invalid child of *any* element *except* a `ul` or `ol`. And no *other* elements are valid children of either a `ul` or `ol`. (This is unlikely to be the source of your problem, but it's far easier to couple JavaScript reliably to valid HTML than broken and and unpredictably browser-corrected, or -salvaged, HTML.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the validate plugin to work, each input must have a `name` attribute.  If you add a unique `name` attribute to each form element, everything will start working.

i.e. change your form elements to look like this:

```
<input class="span12 required" type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"/>
<input class="required span12" type="text" name="middleName" id="middleName"/>
<input class="span12 required" type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"/>
```

See it working here:  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/B78Wt/